# After OnClick is set to null how do I have Onclick behavior again in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have Div element and Im setting its onClick event to null, like this.

```
child.onclick = null;
```

In this case child is a DOM element represent that DIV element.

Now the `onclick` event is no longer there, and now I want to have it again like this.

```
child.onclick = new Function();
```

But that way does not work. I just want to have `onclick` behavior as it was before it is set to null.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('myDiv').onclick= function(){//your code goes here};`

Comment: If you are talking abour removing and attaching onclick functionality on the fly. Surely if you have a named function `function myFunc(){ //code here }` once you've set `child.onclick = null` you can re-attach the functionality you want with `child.onclick = myFunc;` ??

Comment: Once onClick is set to null we can still click on the DIV but nothing is happened. I just want to have the default behavior of onClick event. I do not have any function defined by me.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`:

```
function handler(e){

}
```

to add listener:

```
child.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

to remove:

```
child.removeEventListener('click', handler);
```

**NOTE** as Mark Walters said, use `attachEvent` and `detachEvent` for IE < 9

Comment: please note that `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` are not supported in IE <9.

Comment: No worries. There is a shim included on this page which adds browser support for these function if IE <9 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: Once onClick is set to null we can still click on the DIV but nothing is happened. I just want to have the default behavior of onClick event. I do not have any function defined by me.

Comment: @DilanAlex if no listener is attached to click event, leave it, why setting it to null? if listener IS attached and you want default behavior, then remove listener with `removeEventListener`

Answer (score 2):

```
// save reference to the old callback function
var oldOnclickFn = child.onclick;

// set onclick to null
child.onclick = null;


// set the onclick to the function that was there before.
child.onclick = oldOnclickFn;
```

However, you should probably look into [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = function(){ alert('clicked'); };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pJa9W/